# Getting an infinite loop error when submiting data with React-Query useMutation and react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-query

I have a form where I'm getting values with react-hook-form and sending them to the database with a `useMutation` custom hook.

Here's the data submit:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

const { mutate, isLoading, isError, error } = useCreateTag(tenantId, reset);

const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Tag> = useCallback(
  (values: Tag) => {
    mutate(values);
  },
  [mutate],
);
///
<form
  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
  className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2"
>
```

And here's the custom hook:

```
const createTag = async (values: Tag, tenantId: string) => {
  const body = {
    ...values,
    tenantId,
  };
  const { data } = await axios.post(Routes.API.TAGS, body);
  return data;
};

export const useCreateTag = (tenantId: string, reset: () => void) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (values: Tag) => createTag(values, tenantId),
    onSuccess: () => {
      successToast('Tag created');
      reset();
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['tags', tenantId],
      });
    },
  });
  return mutation;
};
```

The data is sent to the database and the toast is shown so the mutation is a success but I'm still getting this error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I don't understand what could create an infinite loop.